# How to Eliminate Checking of Null Value Datatable in IF condition

Tags: c#, sql-server

In my Page I am fetching a value from the Database & filling the values in the DataTable. I am then comparing that values with the `mac` String in the IF.
Based upon the condition in the Query there will be no records fetched, it is stuck in the IF condition and throws the `No row at Position 0` Exception rather than going into the Else part.

My code is:

```
  string mac = GetMac();
        string Qry = "Select VUserid,Password from passtable where VUserid='" + UserName.Text + "' and Flag='A'";
        string qry = "Select VUserid,Password from passtable where Flag='A'";
        string strq = "Select Mac_id from Sysinfo Where Appflag='A'";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EvalCon"].ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Qry, conn);
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(qry, conn);
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(strq, conn);
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                SqlDataAdapter daa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
                SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
                DataTable tab = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                daa.Fill(dtt);
                dap.Fill(tab);
                for (int i = 0; i < tab.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x <= dtt.Rows.Count - 1; x++)
                    {
                        if (mac == tab.Rows[i]["Mac_id"].ToString() || tab.Rows.Count != 0)
                        {
                            if (UserName.Text == dtt.Rows[x]["VUserid"].ToString() && Password.Text == dtt.Rows[x]["Password"].ToString())
                            {
                                Response.Redirect("~/Changepass.aspx");
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lblMessage.Visible = true;
                                lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                                lblMessage.Text = "Invalid Username or Password !!!";

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lblMessage.Visible = true;
                            lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                            lblMessage.Text = "Invalid Access Point for Evaluation !!!";
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: also apply a condition when `Rows.Count = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you may want to give some more meaningful names to your variables.

On a side note, you may want to change your for loops into a foreach loop:

```
foreach (DataRow tabRow in tab.Rows.Count)
{
    foreach (DataRow dttRow in dtt.Rows.Count)
    {
        // logic here
        // tab.Rows[i]["Mac_id"] becomes tabRow["Mac_id"]
        // and
        // dtt.Rows[x]["VUserid"] becomes dttRow["VUserid"]
        // and so on...
    }
}
```

This way if there are no records fetched it won't go in.

After that, you may want to check the conditions on `RowCount > 0` for the datatables before going inside the loops and act outside the loop if the RowCount is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Just swap your OR condition in If statement:

```
if (tab.Rows.Count != 0 || mac == tab.Rows[i]["Mac_id"].ToString())
{
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check against a null result I'd wrap my if statement in another if statement that does a simple check for a null result before doing anything else. Something like this will check if it's not null:

```
if(tab.rows[i]["Mac_id"] != null)
{
//logic here
}
```

You could add this into your current if statement check so:

```
if(mac == tab.Rows[i]["Mac_id"].ToString() || tab.Rows.Count != 0)
```

becomes:

```
if(mac == tab.Rows[i]["Mac_id"].ToString() || tab.Rows.Count != 0 && tab.rows[i]["Mac_id"] != null)
```

Though as Tallmaris says it might be better to restructure it using a foreach loop instead.